# Load data row by row with python cursor

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I am attempting to parse a very big MySQL table that potentially may not fit in memory. The approach that I am following is, using `pymysql`:

```
db = PyMySQL.connect(**connection_params)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM big_table')
for row in cur:
    process(row)
```

What I am observing is that `cur.execute()` eagerly loads the data into memory. Is it possible to iterate by rows *lazily*?

I am aware this could be done combining `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses, but is it possible to be done in a more transparent way?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of results with that (after `cur.execute`):

```
numrows = cur.rowcount
```

Then, you can iterate over them with a simple for:

```
for num in xrange(0,numrows):
  row = cursor.fetchone()
do stuff...
```

Comment: I am aware that I can iterate over the result of `cur.execute()`, but the issue is that it indeed loads the data and that is not what I `cannot` afford with a very big table.